# Generate Unique Random prominently  color?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to generate Unique and prominently random colors in c# or vb.net. I am using below code now. But this code generating color almost same color, not big change.

How can unique kind of colors?

```
  Private Function GetRandomColor() As Color
        Dim RandGen As New Random()
        Return Color.FromArgb(RandGen.Next(70, 200), RandGen.Next(100, 225), 
        RandGen.Next(100, 230))
    End Function
```

Comment: Just be a little nit-picky -- uniqueness is not a guaranteed quality of random numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random encounter not so random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727538/random-encounter-not-so-random)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try randomly choosing one of the RGB values to be low (0-100).

Answer (score 3):

You would be best using a class that generates HSL colours, that way it is easier to control prominence. There are a few class out  there

Such as...

http://www.geekymonkey.com/Programming/CSharp/RGB2HSL_HSL2RGB.htm

or

http://richnewman.wordpress.com/hslcolor-class/

Having control over the luminosity/saturation means you can get vibrant colours at any hue..

Using richnewmans class...

```
var c = new HSLColor(new Random(0,100),80,80);
```

we only set a random value in the hue and the sat and lum can be fixed at whatever looks best

Answer (score 2):

Its more than likely because you are creating a new instance of Random everytime. Try moving the instance outside of the method, such as at class level, and see if that helps

i.e.

```
  Dim RandGen As New Random()

  Private Function GetRandomColor() As Color
        Return Color.FromArgb(RandGen.Next(70, 200), RandGen.Next(100, 225), 
        RandGen.Next(100, 230))
    End Function
```