# Loto game in c#

Tags: c#

I m trying to make some kind of game with c#, its loto game there is 10 columns. The computer has to generate 6 numbers to fill that 10 columns, my code is like:

```
public static int[] Get() 
    { 
        int[] a = new int[6];
        System.Random r = new System.Random();
        bool flag; int val; 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
        {
            flag = false; 
            do 
            { 
                val = r.Next(1, 50);
                for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k)     
                    if (a[k] == a[i])
                    { 
                        flag = true; 
                        break; 
                    } 
                a[i] = val; 
            } while (flag);  
        } 
        return a;
    }
    public static void Main()
    { 
        int[] a; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
        { 
            a = Get();
            foreach (int x in a)  
                Console.Write("{0} ", x);
            Console.WriteLine(); 
        } 
    }
```

but it gives result same, like

```
4 44 19 44 22 7
4 44 19 44 22 7
4 44 19 44 22 7
4 44 19 44 22 7
4 44 19 44 22 7
4 44 19 44 22 7
4 44 19 44 22 7
4 44 19 44 22 7
4 44 19 44 22 7
22 29 28 15 33 6
```

so whats wrong at my code.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random encounter not so random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727538/random-encounter-not-so-random)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becouse of random class, its default method takes time from computer's current time so you are calling that method at same time and results are same. You can modify code as below

```
 public static int[] Get(System.Random r)
    {
        int[] a = new int[6];
        bool flag;
        int val;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
        {
            flag = false;

            do
            {
                val = r.Next(1, 50);
                for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k)
                    if (a[k] == a[i])
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                a[i] = val;
            } while (flag);
        }

        return a;
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] a;
        System.Random r = new System.Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            a = Get(r);

            foreach (int x in a)
                Console.Write("{0} ", x);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Random` class is seeded from the system time.
When you make lots of `Random`s in a row, they will end up getting created at the same time and will use the same seed.

You should re-use the `Random` instance across calls to `Get()`.